# how to make couch db authentication work

Tags: couchdb

I am having CouchDB installed in a developer environment and exposed the port to public. I have also added admin party. So if I go to http://ip:5984/_utils its asking for username and password which is expected. 
However, if I make the direct request with my db name for example http://ip:5984/{dbname} then its returning json value and also I am able to access this data also via same get request. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set up the database's [security document](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/security.html#put--db-_security) to control which users have what access.  Be sure to read the entire document on [security](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/intro/security.html) so you have a complete understanding of CouchDB's security model, and how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you probably meant that you **Removed** the admin party?

If so, removing admin party only disable annonymous users from doing admin operations. They can still access database.

If you want to restrict access only to authenticated users, you MUST set this configuration value:

```
[couch_httpd_auth]
require_valid_user = true
```

Otherwise, you can set per database permissions (see [Database Security](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/security.html#api-db-security))

Comment: `require_valid_user` is a bad idea in almost all cases.